# C++: Convert string or char to int

Tags: c++, string, types, int, integer

If I have:

```
string number = "45";
```

How do I turn `"45"` into `45` as an integer?

I want to be able to do this:

```
string number + 20 = 65
```

Comment: std::stoi() is built in and can be used

Comment: Try [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "45";
    std::string str2 = "3.14159";
    std::string str3 = "31337 with words";
    std::string str4 = "words and 2";

    int myint1 = std::stoi(str1);
    int myint2 = std::stoi(str2);
    int myint3 = std::stoi(str3);
    // error: 'std::invalid_argument'
    // int myint4 = std::stoi(str4);

    std::cout << "std::stoi(\"" << str1 << "\") is " << myint1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "std::stoi(\"" << str2 << "\") is " << myint2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "std::stoi(\"" << str3 << "\") is " << myint3 << '\n';
    //std::cout << "std::stoi(\"" << str4 << "\") is " << myint4 << '\n';
}
```